# HA cluster with one active name node low performance

Tags: hadoop

iam using hadoop apache 2.7.1 with ha cluster

when i shut down active name node the stand by name  node becomes active 
and that is the normal scenario

but the problem that the performance of the cluster  with one  active namenode decreased  (the operations becomes slower)

and i don't think that ha hadoop cluster  performance should be affected when one name node is active only

i realized that current active namenode log  shows the operation of  trying to connect to previous active shutdown name node

```
Retrying connect to server: mn2/192.168.25.22:8485. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=5
```

i tried to reduce the following properties in core-site

```
<property>
                <name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries.on.timeouts</name>
                <value>5</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>ipc.client.connect.timeout</name>
                <value>1000</value>
        </property>
```

but they have no effect what property should i edit in order to let the current active name node gives up connecting to shutdown namenode

because when i start up previous name node again with no services started yet
the current active name node stops trying to connect to previous active name node 
and the performance of the cluster increased again as there are two name nodes 
even though we have one active name node only

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned in your post which tool you are using for high availability. It seems you are using edits sharing approach between two name nodes for high availability and ‘split brain syndrome’ problem is occurring.

Could you please try some other tools like apache Zookeeper ( or any other tool of your choice ) to achieve the  high availability?

Please Note - If you are using above tools then your quorum should be active in majority. It implies that number of active name nodes should be in odds (3,5,7,etc).

Comment: iam using apache  zookeeper  and Quorum Journal Manager with odd number 5

Comment: @oula - Could you please share the zookeeper's configuration details on server.id=host:port:port. in addition you can refer configuration details mentioned here - https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/setting-namenode-ha

Comment: zookeeper is working well and here are zoo.conf configuration server.1=mn1:2888:3888   

server.2=mn2:2889:3889   

server.3=jn1:2890:3890     

server.4=jn2:2890:3890   

server.5=jn3:2890:3890

Comment: failover is happening with no problems but my problem that the performance decreases when there is only one active name node

Comment: Could you please confirm if all servers are with same hardware configuration?

Comment: all my servers are virtual machines and they have the same hardware configuration

Comment: Could you please investigate the multiple options suggested in another thread - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/36195/possible-reasons-that-cause-slow-name-node-nn.html

Comment: thanks for your reply i think that should help me alot but i should verify new definitions  for me in this link first like jmx metrics ,hdfs audit logs

Comment: i have read this url and get confused https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2015/07/01/impact-namenode-transitioning-connected-clients/

Comment: it describes that when we connect to cluster through active name node directly the performance will be less and that is my state i am using an application and connect to active name node ip directly ,then send webhdfs requests

Comment: what is the relation of failover proxy provider to my state

Comment: Have you checked the below as suggested earlier -https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/36195/possible-reasons-that-cause-slow-name-node-nn.html. If yes then could you provide logs

Comment: there are a lot of jmx metrics which are on port  50070/jmx whicj i should concentrate on ,and what do they mean by hdfs audit log are they the logs of namenode ,journal nodes and etc

Comment: supposing we have two namenodes mn1 and mn2 i recently realized that when mn1 is off and mn2 is active the performance is ok   but when mn2 is off and mn1 is active the performance decreases what could be the reason of performance differences between active name nodes

Comment: in order to analyze my problem and because i am working on virtual machines i copied second name node virtual machine (i mean the name node which behaves well and change it's ip and host name to be the same of first name node which is slower so i have same network and software configuration) and i got the same results, what a strange state it's related to hostname only ,

Comment: i will mention my problem again when mn1 is off and mn2 is active and on and ever thing is ok ,but when mn2 is off and mn1 is active , mn1 responds slower as data nodes send requests to this dead mn2 name node host name and i don't know why and that's of ocourse when issuing webhdfs requests only and not on hdfs commands eventhough my requests are directed to active name node from client application